# Inverse of an element of a quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x) \in Q[x]/\langle x-5\rangle$, then how to construct $f^{-1}(x)$? [The unity in $Q[x]/\langle x-5\rangle$ is $1 + \langle x-5\rangle$, am I right?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ x\!-\!5\!:\ x\equiv 5\ \Rightarrow\ f(x) \equiv f(5)\in \Bbb Q$

Comment: couldn't follow you. Is there everything ok with what you typed ? can you please check once ?

Comment: @Sourav What part could you not follow?

Comment: Did you mean 5 = x mod (x-5)

Comment: Yes, $\rm\, mod\ g\!:\ \cdots\,$ means $\rm\,\cdots \pmod g$

Comment: The notation simply moves the mod to the start (vs. end) of the statement, which tells you at the *start* where the arithmetic is taking place (esp. useful when the end is visually far away).

Comment: Was I right right about the unity of the given quotient field ? is it 1 + <x-5> or not ?

Comment: Yes. But the questions you pose lead me to suspect that you don't yet have a firm conceptual grasp of quotient rings. Perhaps you should review that material and/or ask some questions here on such.

Comment: You are right and I am learning a lot of stuff in a very little time so shaky at present. i need another 24 hours or so to be firm on this. Thanks a lot for your help.